# Run javascript at plovr compile-time

Tags: javascript, google-closure, compile-time, plovr

Is it possible to run javascript at compile time using plovr? (perhaps defining a variable in the config file).

For example, I would like a function that returns the time the script was compiled, something like this:

```
function compiledAt(){
    return #Date.now(); // #Date.now() to be processed at compile-time
}
```

So that after compilation, it would look like this:

```
function compiledAt(){
    return 1374580397271;
}
```

Comment: You can use Ant task replace for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few months later, I can update that it is **not** possible to do this using only javascript and Plovr.

Other options include:

1. A script that makes a replace and then runs plover
2. A customer compiler pass in Google Closure